# When did Pebbles and Bamm-Bamm get introduced?

Tags: character, flintstones

I know they were introduced in the later seasons, but I'm not sure exactly when Pebbles and Bamm-Bamm were introduced respectively. When were they introduced into *The Flintstones* anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Wikipedia, [Pebbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pebbles_Flintstone) was introduced in the Season 3 episode "The Blessed Event", in which Wilma gives birth to her, while [Bamm-Bamm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamm-Bamm_Rubble) was introduced in the Season 4 episode "Little Bamm-Bamm", in which he is left on the Rubble's doorstep.